# Angular 7: Импорт глобального less в component.less

Tags: angular, less

У меня меня есть файл material.less, в котором я объявил переменные.
Теперь хочу использовать их в компонентах, но приложение позволяет делать @import только в app.component.less, а в дочерних компонентах отказывается видеть глобальный файл.

```
@material-primary: #2196f3; //light-blue accent-3
@material-accent: #00897b; // teal darken-1
@material-warning: #ff6d00; // orange accent-4
@material-disabled: #a7a7a7;

// Mode: Phone
@phone: 360px;
@phone-area: 350px;

// Mode: Tablet
@tablet: 768px;
@tablet-area: 750px;

// Mode: Desktop
@desktop: 1024px;
@desktop-area: 970px;
```

Итак, что я пробовал?

1. Самое очевидное - в файле bottom-navigation.component.less делаю

   `@import "..../assets/styles/material-theme";`

Ошибка такая:

> @import "..../assets/styles/material-theme";
>   ^
>   Can't resolve './..../assets/styles/material-theme.less' in 'D:....\src\app\components\layout\bottom-navigation'
>         in D:....\src\app\components\layout\bottom-navigation\bottom-navigation.component.less (line 1, column 0)
>   ERROR in ./src/app/components/layout/bottom-navigation/bottom-navigation.component.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './.../assets/styles/material-theme.less' in 'D:.....\src\app\components\layout\bottom-navigation'
>   i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

2. В файле bottom-navigation.component.ts пытаюсь подключить дополнительный файл

   `styleUrls: [
      './bottom-navigation.component.less',
      '.../assets/styles/material-theme.less'
   ]`

Ошибка такая:

> ERROR in ./src/app/components/layout/bottom-navigation/bottom-navigation.component.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './.../assets/styles/material-theme.less' in 'D:...\src\app\components\layout\bottom-navigation'
>   i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
>   i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...

3. Пытаюсь сделать файл глобальным, объявив его в angular.json

   `"test": {
         "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
         "options": {
           "main": "src/test.ts",
           "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
           "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
           "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
           "styles": [
             "src/assets/styles/material-theme.scss",
             "src/assets/styles/material-theme.less",
             "src/assets/styles/app.less"
           ],
           "scripts": [],
           "assets": [
             "src/favicon.ico",
             "src/assets"
           ]
         }
       },`

Нет результата.

4. Сделал компонент полностью нейтральным, с независимыми цветами.

   ```
   .toolbar-item{

   &.active{
     color: #000;

     mat-icon{
       color: #000;
     }

     .toolbar-item-text {
       color: #000;
     }
   }

   mat-icon{
     color: #aaaaaa;
   }

   .toolbar-item-text{
     color: #aaaaaa;
   }
   ```

в app.less переопределяю

```
    .toolbar-item {
        &.active {
            color: @material-primary;
            mat-icon {
                color: @material-primary;
            }
            .toolbar-item-text {
                color: @material-primary;
            }
        }
        mat-icon {
            color: @material-disabled;
        }
        .toolbar-item-text {
            color: @material-disabled;
        }
    }
```

но внезапно стили компонента в браузере гасят глобальный стиль, и я в пролёте.

Как настроить импорт стилей в компоненты для LESS, и только LESS?

Comment: по-моему ответ очевидный - у вас неправильные пути, в `styleUrls` по стайлаугду ангуляра должен быть один путь к стилю компонента - ВСЕ!

Comment: Нет, пути исключаются. Я даже делал подключение лесенкой - сначала в одной папке с компонентом, потом на директорию выше, потом ещё выше. Ошибка появляется, когда файл оказывается в корне папки components. Полный путь "/src/...." тоже пробовал, не работает.

Comment: почитайте про `stylePreprocessorOptions`

Comment: тоже пробовал, никаких изменений.

Comment: Файл ангулара у меня называется angular.json, а не angular-cli.json. Это имеет какое-то значение? Использую cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971392/stylepreprocessoroptions-not-working-on-angular-cli-7

добавить в angular.json projects..architect.build.options.stylePreprocessorOptions.includePaths путь к папке с глобальными стилями.

При этом обратить внимание на значение  projects..root если "" то прописывать путь относительно текущей папки (например: "src/styles").

Папку со стилями желательно ложить в src (я делаю так, у меня работает).

Далее в less файлах компонентов прописывать @import "<имя файла>" (для импорта /src/styles.variables.less будет @import "variables")